# Responsive iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

i'm struggling to get a responsive `iframe` but so far nothing.. 
I use the following css and html.thanks in advance.

```css
.testme_container {
position: relative;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
 
.testme_container-16x9 {
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
 
.testme_container-4x3 {
padding-bottom: 75%;
}
 
.testme_container iframe {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="testme_container">
<iframe src="http://www.gmail.com" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but "so far nothing" is not a very good problem description. Can you specify what you are trying to achieve and what happens instead?

Comment: Think i already did.. trying to achieve responsive iframe.. but unfortunately doesnt work.. what kind of description you expect.. If you run the snippet you ll see that nothing happens... :( Let me know how can i address my problem better and i will for sure :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to explain in detail what you want to achieve?

I tried your code and judging by the names of your CSS classes (16x9, 4x3) it seems to work fine, however, you will have to use a different URL to test it:

```
<div class="testme_container testme_container-4x3">
      <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/egezoftw/1/)

The reason www.gmail.com doesn't show up is, because Google doesn't allow it to be displayed in an iframe. If you look at the jsfiddle you can see, I did not change anything about your code but the link and I added the class "testme_container-4x3".

Comment: Oh i see! But i place gmail only for proving my point, not that i will use that link.. When i tried with different link it didnt work as well.. Well anyway the think is that i want to place an iframe on a website that it can be responsive. No borders no scroll to be need if you watch it over tablets phones or different resolutions etc...

Comment: Are you talking about the scrollbar of the main page or the scrollbar of the iframe? If you are talking about the scrollbar of the main page, you are on the right track. Unfortunately resizing the content of the iframe to fit its size is a little more complicated, I am not even sure if it can be done.

Comment: OOOOOHHHHH now i get it... Well anyway guys i completely stupid i think.. The iframe is responsive but i was thinking that i can interfere also with the content of the website i ll use in the iframe...  PFFFffffffff!!! sorry guys for wasting your time :P thanks

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript function relies on jQuery to make all iframes on the page responsive. It handles video embeds to preserve their aspect ratio without extra vertical or horizontal margin but you need to determine the aspect ratio you'll be using in your embedded video.

https://gist.github.com/dylanvalade/b2ba4eaa99ae7968cfd8

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in native javascript without any need to rely on jQuery or other framework/library. [Responsive Iframes](https://github.com/taylordaughtry/responsive-iframes) would work perfectly for this.